# How can i declare a multi dimensional array in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I have an array as follows:

```
 $apps = @('app1', 'app1a', 'app1b', 'app2', 'app2a', 'app2b')
```

Now app1 , app1a and app1b are all related, so I want them in one item in the array and able to access:

I have tried:

```
$test = @{test1 = (app,app1a,app1b);test2 = (app2,app2a,app2b);}

 foreach($item in $test.GetEnumerator()){
  $key = $item.key
  $value = $item.value
  Write-Output $key $value
 }
```

But i want to access each item in the array and then each item in that .
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>To answer the question implied by your post's *title*: `[string[,]]::new(3,2)` creates a *true two-dimensional array* in PowerShell that would fit your data, but such arrays are *rarely needed* in PowerShell.</sup>

To work with [*arrays*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays) only (`@(...)`) - as opposed to [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`) - use a *jagged* array:

```bash
# Note: You could enclose the entire RHS in @(...) too, but it isn't necessary.
#       For the same reason, the following is sufficient:
#          $apps = ('app1', 'app1a', 'app1b'), ('app2', 'app2a', 'app2b')
$apps = @('app1', 'app1a', 'app1b'), @('app2', 'app2a', 'app2b')
```

That is, `$apps` is then an *array of arrays*, specifically a two-element array whose elements are themselves arrays.

Then, `$apps[0]` yields `@('app1' 'app1a', 'app1b')`, and `$apps[1]` yields `@('app2', 'app2a', 'app2b')`, and you can use *nested* indexing to access individual elements in either; e.g. `$apps[0][1]` yields `'app1a'`

To *enumerate* the elements in each "dimension" using a [`foreach` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach), use something like:

```bash
# Outputs '[app1]', '[app1a]', and '[app1b]', each on its own line.
foreach ($el in $apps[0]) { "[$el]" }
```

---

If you do want to use *hashtables*:

```bash
$apps = @{
  test1 = @('app1', 'app1a', 'app1b')
  test2 = @('app2', 'app2a', 'app2b')
}
```

Then you can use, e.g. `$apps['test1'][1]` as well as `$apps.test1[1]` to retrieve `'app1a'`

To *enumerate* the elements associated with a given key  using `foreach`, use something like:

```bash
# Outputs '[app1]', '[app1a]', and '[app1b]', each on its own line.
foreach ($el in $apps.test1) { "[$el]" }
```

Comment: @Traci, yes, as with any array / most enumerables - please see my update.